# Get external claims using Google AccessToken in Asp.Net Core API 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using JSON Web Token (Bearer) as my default Authentication. I'm then using (Cookies) as my Authentication for Google.

I am using the default Google Authentication in Asp.Net Core API to get the AccessToken. I then pass that AccessToken to my Angular application in the Url, using a redirect. This is similar to how the ASP.Net MVC 5 Web API works. From there, I'm making a call back to my Asp.Net Core API to try and get the remaining claims. I'm making the call using the AccessToken.

Does anyone know how to access the external claims using the Google AccessToken? I know how to do this in the Asp.Net MVC 5 Web API, but Asp.Net Core is much different.

I can see external claims here. This happens during the OAuth process after the User Authenticates with Google. This is in my ExternalLoginCallback method.

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Here is some information that seems to be useful, but it doesn't specifically address third party Auth.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.2

If I call the API using the AccecssToken, in the header, and use HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync like so....

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

I get this.

{System.Exception: No SecurityTokenValidator available for token: ya29.Glt5B_thgPhe8-FcR

Thanks in advance! Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. Since I'm able to get the claims from the Cookie in my ExternalLoginCallback method, I went ahead and created a new JSON Web Token (JWT), added the extracted claims to it and then passed that over to my Angular application. Now, when I make the call back to my API, I'm able to read that Token and extract the claims using this line of code in my GetUserInfo method.

```
HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Bottom line, since I could not read the Google AccessToken like I could in my ASP.Net MVC 5 Web API, I just went ahead and created a new JWT Token, added in the claims and used that.

By the way, I'm having to do all of this because I can not call my ExternalLogin method directly from Angular because of a known Cors policy issue.

Comment: `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` did not work for me